# PayFast Notify Url not hit c# core

Tags: c#, payment

I am using Pay-fast Payment Gateway but I have an issue that not call
notify URL so I am not getting any response. I have share a video link.

**Video Link**- https://www.screencast.com/t/QNPUcorwY

I do not understand how to get response and save to my database. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Are you able to add your code to the question please. Also, you might find quite a lot of people can't see your video as it requires Flash Player. Are you able to add any relevant details to your question?

Comment: The PayFast ITN payload gets sent to your notify_url as per the docs, however if your notify_url is not publicly accessible when deving locally, then PayFast will not be able to post to your notify_url, and send you the ITN. Make sure your notify_url returns a 200 response, if it is not publicly accessible, then you can look at using a tunneling service like ngrok for your local URLs